# Insertar registro de c# a sql envia TextBox1 nullReference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

necesito saber porque mi codigo no funciona, en ocasiones anteriores funcionaba perfectamente pero al crear un proyecto nuevo me evia un error que no entiendo porque sucede

el codigo de la funcion es la siguiente:

```
 public void insertarCliente(String ide, String nom, String tel, String direc, String correo, String fech) {
        try
        {
            cn.conectarBase();
            comando.Connection = cn.getCon();

            SqlCommand insercion = new SqlCommand("insert into CLIENTES (Identificacion,NombreCliente,Telefono,Direccion,Correo,FechaRegistro) "
                + "values (@ide,@nom,@tel,@direc,@correo,@fech)", cn.getCon());

            odataAdapter.InsertCommand = insercion;
            odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ide", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nom", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tel", SqlDbType.NChar));
            odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@direc", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@correo", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fech", SqlDbType.NVarChar));

        }
        catch (SqlException e) { }
        finally { cn.desconectar(); }
    }
```

y cuando llamo el procedimiento

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text.Equals("") || textBox3.Text.Equals("") || textBox4.Text.Equals("") || textBox5.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Faltan datos por Completar");
        }
        else
        {
            m.insertarCliente(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text,textBox4.Text,textBox5.Text,textBox6.Text);

            m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@ide"].Value = textBox1;
            m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@nom"].Value = textBox2;
            m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@tel"].Value = textBox3;
            m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@direc"].Value = textBox4;
            m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@correo"].Value = textBox5;
            m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@fech"].Value = textBox6;

            m.cn.conectarBase();
            int result = m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            m.cn.desconectar();
            MessageBox.Show("Cliente Agregado Correctamente");
            limpiar();
            bloquear();

        }
    }
```

pero cuando le doy al boton me sale el error de

```
 Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
```

pero si existe el objeto y antes de ese procedimiento lo utilizo

Comment: referencia a cual de todos los objetos que hay ahi?? puedes rastrear especificamente cual?

Comment: donde esta definido odataAdapter y como?

Comment: el odataAdapter esta definido como : public SqlDataAdapter odataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

Comment: y el objeto que me tira referencia es textBox1

Comment: ok, varias cosas de esto no me cierran.. para que le pasas los datos al procedimiento insertarcliente si alli no haces nada con esos. textBox1 no puede ser nulo si esta definido en el mismo form.. el odataadapter esta definido a nivel de clase? y mas alla de hacerle el new, en algun momento seguro lo estas limpiando pq si no seria ilogico cargarle siempre el mismo query de insercion. fijate de detallar todas esas cosas, pero sigo insistiendo que odataadapter es el null...

Comment: Has importado las librerias Data y Data.Sql en tu nuevo proyecto?

Comment: Hola, lo primero es preguntarte en qué linea de tu código se genera la excepción. Cuando tengas esa línea pon un punto de ruptura, depura y revisa el contenido de las variables. Como bien dijo @gbianchi, para mí el problema es que no has instanciado o la variable `m` o `m.odataAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el fallo está en que pasas el objeto entero en lugar de su valor de texto; además usas una función redundante. Yo lo solucionaría así:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text.Equals("") || textBox3.Text.Equals("") || textBox4.Text.Equals("") || textBox5.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Faltan datos por Completar");
    }
    else
    {
        m.cn.conectarBase();

        SqlCommand insercion = new SqlCommand("insert into CLIENTES (Identificacion,NombreCliente,Telefono,Direccion,Correo,FechaRegistro) "
            + "values (@ide,@nom,@tel,@direc,@correo,@fech)", m.cn.getCon());

        // Definimos los parámetros:
        insercion.Parameters.Add("@ide", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        insercion.Parameters.Add("@nom", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        insercion.Parameters.Add("@tel", SqlDbType.NChar));
        insercion.Parameters.Add("@direc", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        insercion.Parameters.Add("@correo", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        insercion.Parameters.Add("@fech", SqlDbType.NVarChar));

        // Nos aseguramos que es un nuevo DataAdapter
        m.odataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand = insercion;

        // Le pasamos el texto que contienen los distintos objetos textBox
        m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@ide"].Value = textBox1.Text;
        m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@nom"].Value = textBox2.Text;
        m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@tel"].Value = textBox3.Text;
        m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@direc"].Value = textBox4.Text;
        m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@correo"].Value = textBox5.Text;
        m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@fech"].Value = textBox6.Text;

        int result = m.odataAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        m.cn.desconectar();
        MessageBox.Show("Cliente Agregado Correctamente");
        limpiar();
        bloquear();

    }
}
```